# What is better: iSCSI or NFS for mysql datadir mount?

Tags: mysql, nfs, iscsi, synology

There is database server with ip-address in external zone with mysql instances and nas-storage existing in internal zone. I need that database file is located in storage. I want write in my.cnf for example:

```
[mysqld1]
port       = 3306
datadir    = /data/sql/mysqld1

[mysqld2]
port       = 3307
datadir    = /nasstorage/sql_on_storage/mysqld2
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

I am planning to mount directory from storage to database server. Which is technology is better for this puspose: iSCSI or NFS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Network filesystems and databases can be a problematic combo, and at least InnoDB does not like NFS. From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-init-startup-configuration.html)

> If reliability is a consideration for your data, do not configure
>   InnoDB to use data files or log files on NFS volumes. Potential
>   problems vary according to OS and version of NFS, and include such
>   issues as lack of protection from conflicting writes, and limitations
>   on maximum file sizes.

So I would go ahead with iSCSI instead. Whatever you decide to use, please benchmark & stress-test it to see how reliable your choice is.

Comment: that is true. However, some NFS vendos (no name, it's a network appliance, hint), do have best practices for running mysql on NFS volumes (see http://www.netapp.com/us/media/tr-3657.pdf, point 3.6: Linux nfs protocol, page 11).

Comment: I still suspect that under heavy load and some strange conditions that can be very error-prone thing to do.

Comment: @natxoasenjo your link is to a NetApp paper from 2010 that deals with MySQL 5.0.  This link might be more up-to-date: https://kb.netapp.com/support/s/article/ka21A0000000WkTQAU/what-are-the-mount-options-for-databases-on-netapp-nfs

Comment: Link update https://kb.netapp.com/Advice_and_Troubleshooting/Data_Storage_Software/ONTAP_OS/What_are_the_mount_options_for_databases_on_NetApp_NFS%3F. Found some optimization steps in a blog post https://www.ajohnstone.com/achives/optimizing-mysql-over-nfs-with-netapp/